# How to update SDK reference that doesn't exist in project (ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: java, kotlin, android-studio, gradle, google-play-console

I am getting this error in play console:

> Your latest production release (4 (1.2.1)) contains SDK issues
> Aug 26, 2023 23:50
> com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:17.1.2
> This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Upgrade to a newer version (19.3.0+).
>
> Starting from November 26, 2023 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release new versions which contain this SDK version. com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2
> This SDK version has been reported as outdated. Upgrade to a newer version (19.4.0+).
>
> This SDK version has a note from the SDK developer. Here's what the SDK developer told us:
>
> This version is officially deprecated, and will soon disable ad loading. Please update to a new version. See https://developers.google.com/admob/android/deprecation for more details.
>
> Starting from November 26, 2023 00:00 (UTC) you won't be able to release new versions which contain this SDK version.

The issue is I've looked EVERYWHERE for this dependency and I can't find it. Where do I upgrade these types of dependencies? The documentation isn't clear either.